# Convergence of $\sum _{n=3} ^\infty \frac 1 {(\ln \ln n)^{\ln \ln n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum _{n=3} ^\infty \frac 1 {(\ln \ln n)^{\ln \ln n}} .$$

I believe the series diverges. I am thinking of using the integral test to show this, but I am not sure if that is right.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\log(\log(n))$ is monotonically increasing, we can write

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log(\log(n))^{\log(\log(n))}}{n}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log(\log(x))^{\log(\log(x))}}{x}$$

Then, letting $x=e^{e^u}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log(\log(n))^{\log(\log(n))}}{n}&=\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{u^u}{e^{e^u}}\\\\
&=\lim_{u\to \infty}e^{u\log(u)-e^{u}}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Thus, for sufficiently large $n$, $\frac{1}{\log(\log(n))^{\log(\log(n))}}>\frac1n$.   Since the harmonic series diverges, then the series

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{\log(\log(n))^{\log(\log(n))}}\,\,\text{diverges also!}$$

Answer (score 0):

This series is **divergent**.

The general term is decreasing then one may apply the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), thus the initial series behaves like
$$
\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{2^p}{(\ln p+\ln(\ln 2))^{\ln p+\ln(\ln 2)}}
$$ which is divergent since
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{2^p}{(\ln p+\ln(\ln 2))^{\ln p+\ln(\ln 2)}}=+\infty\neq0.
$$

Comment: is there a p-series sequence I can compare this too to show it diverges?

Comment: You could probably find an (artificial) $p$-series which diverges, but I think one would rather focus on why the general term above does *not* tend to $0$ as $p \to \infty$.